# Which way is more right using Generics or Inheritance?

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance, interface

I am trying to apply new contracts to our icons system and we ran into this argument which way is more right??

(the resulted interface is the same):

**Using Generic ->** the interface is less clear but we receive auto-complete and compilation errors with 0 effort once the type property is set

**No using Generic ->** Will require the developer to do ‘as AccountIcon’ (or another type) for any object the expects to receive Icon

## Inhertience example

```
export interface Icon {
  type: 'account' | 'img' | 'font-icon';
}

export interface AccountIcon extends Icon {
  readonly type: 'account';
  value: LinkIcon<LinkIconType>;
}
export interface ImgIcon extends Icon {
  readonly type: 'img';
  value: Icon;
}
export interface FontIcon extends Icon {
  readonly type: 'font-icon';
  value: string;
}
```

## Generics example

```
export interface FilterIcon<T extends IconType> {
  readonly type: T;
  value: T extends 'account' ? LinkIcon<LinkIconType> : T extends 'font-icon' ? string : Icon;
}

export type IconType = 'font-icon' | 'img' | 'account';
```

Comment: What if IconType will contain 100 of allowed strings?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, my first question here, I edited the post to include code

Comment: @captain-yossarian I agree that the ternary condition is not amazing and readable, but this is what Typescript provides today.
I could create 'better' conditions using an abstract class but for now it's a bit overkill and less clean

Comment: A slight error in first example ImgIcon both extends Icon and uses it in value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a discriminated union.

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions

```
export interface AccountIcon {
  readonly type: 'account';
  value: LinkIcon<LinkIconType>;
}

export interface ImgIcon {
  readonly type: 'img';
  value: IconValue;
}

export interface FontIcon {
  readonly type: 'font-icon';
  value: string;
}

export type Icon = AccountIcon | ImgIcon | FontIcon;
```

This matches your use case logically - you have multiple types of icons, but sometimes you may want to want to work with them in general without knowing specific type.

The advantage here is that typescript is smart enough to figure out type when you check for type in conditions:

```
if (icon.type === 'img') {
  // Typescript knows icon is an ImgIcon 
} else {
  // Typescript knows that icon is not an ImgIcon.
}
```

Comment: But what about this case
Generics
`
interface MenuItem{
title:string;
icon: Icon<IconType>
}
`
let items: MenuItem[] = [
{title: 'lorem' icon: {type: 'img' value: 'path/to/img'}
]


Inheritence
```
interface MenuItem{
title:string;
icon: Icon
}
```
let items: MenuItem[] = [
{title: 'lorem' icon: {type: 'img' value: 'path/to/img'} as ImgIcon (I have to add as ImgIcon for typeproffing)
]

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Icon union will work fine when used in other interfaces. Also, note that my response had a mistake where Icon type was used in two places. Maybe that was a source of confusion.